# Instance deployment failed to install Composer dependencies specified in 'composer.json' in your source bundle

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

The same code, works with my other server, But it returns error like below.
Couldnt understand whats wrong.

```
  - Installing phpunit/phpunit (9.5.5): Extracting archive
  - Installing predis/predis (v1.1.7): Extracting archive
  - Installing paragonie/sodium_compat (v1.16.1): Extracting archive
  - Installing pusher/pusher-php-server (v4.1.5): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/psr-http-message-bridge (v2.1.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-uuid (v1.23.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing nyholm/psr7 (1.4.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing symfony/http-client (v5.3.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing sentry/sentry (3.2.2): Extracting archive
  - Installing sentry/sdk (3.1.0)
  - Installing sentry/sentry-laravel (2.6.0): Extracting archive
  - Installing yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle (v9.18.0): Extracting archive
65 package suggestions were added by new dependencies, use `composer suggest` to see details.
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
 

2021/06/15 17:47:24.504882 [INFO] Executing cleanup logic
2021/06/15 17:47:24.505070 [INFO] CommandService Response: {"status":"FAILURE","api_version":"1.0","results":[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"Engine execution has encountered an error.","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Instance deployment failed to install Composer dependencies specified in 'composer.json' in your source bundle. The deployment failed.","timestamp":1623779244,"severity":"ERROR"},{"msg":"Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.","timestamp":1623779244,"severity":"ERROR"}]}]}
```

Comment: did you find any solution ?

Comment: did you find any solution bro? please provide me